# How to set the first order status as a custom status for newly created orders from Woocommerce Rest API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

We use a platform called BaseLinker, which sends orders from other marketplaces to our WooCommerce store through Rest API. The problem is that initially the orders have a status of "Payment Pending," then "Processing," and the final status remains "Processing," triggering automated emails and SMS messages. However, our contracts with other marketplaces clearly specify that we cannot contact external customers except directly through them.

We created a custom status with the slug "baselinker," and from their platform, we had the option to set which status new orders should receive. Currently, it is as follows: "Payment Pending" -> "Processing" -> "BaseLinker." Once it reaches the "Processing" status, the emails and SMS messages are automatically sent. How can we prevent new orders created through Rest API from receiving the "Processing" status at all?

I've tried this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'custom_set_order_status', 10, 1);

function custom_set_order_status($order_id) {
    if (!$order_id) return;

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-json/wc/') !== false) {
        // Set the order status
        $order->update_status('baselinker', 'Order status changed to BaseLinker automatically by custom code.', true);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, not much is happening. It was doing exactly what the platform does, changing the status from "Processing" to "BaseLinker." This code doesn't make sense because their platform already does this.
However, the action of this code was faster than the action in the respective platform. In the sense that the first status was "BaseLinker," then "Pending," then "Processing."

Comment: Order status depends on payment method. So each payment method may have different status. Paying with credit/debit will expect either fail status or complete status. COD or cheque are with processing status etc.. so if you want default status to be your status you have to change payment method settings.

Comment: We only have two payment methods. COD and credit/debit. Even if we have those two, that platform will automatically create new orders the same way. first "pending" then "processing", not taking count of the payment method.

Comment: If you check the diagram on https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-automatically-complete-woocommerce-orders-when-they-go-to-the-processing-status/, it says that "Pending" is set by WooCommerce itself, when a new order is made. I think your best bet is probably to use the `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook. When the order comes in, "mark" it as a BaseLinker order by adding some meta data, and then when the hook fires again for future status changes, you can check on that, and then determine yourself what the next status should be.

Comment: Last idea I had was to delay the triggers for new order and for the SMS sending functions, but not sure how to make it work, because it needs to cancel the process if the status has changed from "Pending".